# Call CRM 2011 Services by Sharepoint site

Tags: web-services, integration, dynamics-crm

I'm on my first SP/ CRM 2011 project.
I'm working on a Sharepoint site that could  send data to CRM 2011. 
For example: 
On sharepoint I have a custom form that should send data to a CRM Entity.

Could anybody tell how should be the network be Set? Should I have both CRM and SP on the same macchine ? How could pass data to CRM ?  Should I Write a new Web services?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the servers are on the same network there should not be any severe problems.

Dynamics CRM has two great web services for doing CRUD operations on the data and also for getting metadata information from the CRM.
Here is the technet starting point for learning to work with these web services http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309557.aspx

Here is more about how to use the Organization service that you use to access and modify data http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309449.aspx

Here is an example for doing CRUD with late bound http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx

These web services can e.g. be accessed from the code behind of a webpart. One of the trickier part is the authentication against the CRM, here is tons of information on that matter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328497.aspx

There is also tons of information and resources regarding these topics spread all over the web, use your favorite search engine to find them!

Oh and by the way, using these web services requires SharePoint 2013, since 2010 has a lower .net version than CRM 2011. For 2010 you would need to use the legacy .asmx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151015.aspx) which is a bit more painful to use!

Best of luck